# Numbers vs Non-numbers in String validation

Tags: sql, oracle, validation

I would like to ask for advice on records testing.

At this point, I have an `account` field that must consist of numbers only. Nevertheless, this is a `varchar` field because of the leading zeroes.

I had this query that actually shows me non-digits in the account number (or null).

`LTRIM(TRANSLATE(ACCOUNT,'0123456789',' '),' ') INVALID_DATA`

Nevertheless, I just faced another issue- spaces are not taken into account, and therefore if account has a space, it goes unnoticed as `null`. Yes, I can replace space with something more recognizable, but will it be enough? I am sure there are other exceptions I don't know about.

Is there any universal way to check for ANY POSSIBLE variation that is not a number? maybe something like this? How reliable is it?

`LENGTH(ACCOUNT)-LENGTH(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE((ACCOUNT), '[^[:digit:]]+', ''))) NON-NUMBERS`

Also, how to detect and account for cases with non-Unicode characters?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a regexp_replace approach to find non-numbers in a string:

```
regexp_replace(account, '\d+')
```

**Explanation**

-The escape character, `\d`, is metacharacter for a digit character.

-The `+` symbol is a quantifier indicating one or more instances of this digit.

Thus, we are removing all digits from the account column and where this is non-null,
you have non-number left.
~~~~~~~~~~~~

With respect to your calculation:

```
LENGTH(ACCOUNT)-LENGTH(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE((ACCOUNT), '[^[:digit:]]+', ''))) NON-NUMBERS
```

Your reg expression looks for non-digits and removes them.  Your approach will work (I do not like converting the string to a number then dynamically casting as a string). If you use this in a condition, it would need to be encapsulated in a NVL function like this:

```
NVL(LENGTH(ACCOUNT)-LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(ACCOUNT, '[^[:digit:]]+', '')),0)  NON-NUMBERS
```

Comment: how it's any different from my solution `[^[:digit:]]+`?

Comment: your approach is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea:

```
LTRIM(TRANSLATE(ACCOUNT, ' 0123456789', 'X'), ' ') as INVALID_DATA
```

Should return a non-empty string when there is a space.

In a `where` clause you would use:

```
where LENGTH( LTRIM(TRANSLATE(ACCOUNT, ' 0123456789', 'X'), ' ')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all spaces like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(fld_or_variable, ' ', '')
```

Or you can trim spaces like this

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(' Amit Tech Corp '))
```